# Order of promise execution from function

Tags: javascript, promise

I have to execute a Fetch promise return inside a function in order to convert some data before someone else could handle this data. 
So I created this code (simplified just to show the idea):

```
function test() {

  return  new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    // Fetch('www.google.com')
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
  }).then(function () {
    // convert data, etc
    console.log(1);
  });
}
// after conversion, handle it to someone else
test().then(console.log(2));
```

Running it, I thought that console would show: 1 2 but it keeps showing 2 1. Is there other way to do this?

Comment: You need to pass `.then()` a *function*. `test().then(function(){ console.log(2) });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you did with the `console.log(1)`, you need to wrap the second call in a function before passing it to `then` as a *callback*.

```
test().then(function() {
    console.log(2);
});
```

Then it will show `1` `2` as expected.